# How to format a string through String.Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, string.format

Numeric

```
  string a = String.Format("{0:#/#}",12)
```

output:1/2

But How to Convert it for string Suppose

```
  String b=String.Format("{0:###-#}","test")
```

Output : test

Expected Output: tes-t

Comment: # is a digit placeholder format. It doesn't denote 'characters'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't format a string through `string.Format` for the reason that it is *already* a string.

If you want to manipulate the string, use the methods defined on the `string` class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can split the string to its characters and then use format

```
string testString = "test";
string formattedString = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}-{3}", testString.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray());
```